# Improve logic to find cyclic rotation on given string1 can produce string2

Tags: scala, logic

Find if the cyclic rotation on given `string1` can produce `string2`?

Examples:-

string1 = `abcd`

string2 = `cdab`

### output = `true`

string1 = `abc`

string2 = `bac`

### output = `false`

I'm trying to improve this logic by reducing the complexity from `n^2` to `n`, and `n` to `n-k` by making this `checkRotation` function to terminate after finding the first `true`.

```
//complexity n^2
def checkRotation(string1: String, string2: String): Boolean = {
  for (i <- 0 until string1.length) yield {
    for (j <- 0 until string2.length) yield {
      if (string1.charAt(i) == string2.charAt(j)) {
        string1 == string2.substring(j) + "" + string2.substring(0, j)
      } else {
        false
      }
    }
  }
}.flatten.contains(true)
```

---

```
//complexity n
  def checkRotation(string1: String, string2: String, index: Int = 0): Boolean = {
    if (index < string2.length) {
      if (string1.charAt(0) != string2.charAt(index)) {
        checkRotation(string1, string2, index + 1)
      } else {
        string1 == string2.substring(index) + "" + string2.substring(0, index)
      }
    } else {
      false
    }
  }
```

Any improvements? Thanks!!!

EDIT

```
 def checkRotation(string1: String, string2: String, index: Int = 0): Boolean = {
    if (index < string2.length && (string1.charAt(0) != string2.charAt(index)
        || !string1.contains(string2.substring(index) + "" + string2.substring(0, index)))) {
      checkRotation(string1, string2, index + 1)
    } else {
      index < string2.length
    }
  }
```

Comment: 2nd one doesn't actually work: `checkRotation("aabc","abca")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
(string1 + string1).contains(string2)
```